# Como resolver problemas de acentuação com ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Estou tendo problemas com acentuação no ASP.NET MVC 5.

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2013 Professional e na aplicação o .Net 4.5. SQL Server 2008 e o Entity Framework 6. O browser é o Google Chrome atualizado e o Windows é o 8.1.

Exemplo:

Onde quero que apareça `"Endereço"` está aparecendo `"EndereÃ§o"`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Isso é um problema de codificação de caracteres. Qual é a codificação que estás a usar na página ou website?

Comment: Na página eu estou colocando lang pt-Br, charset utf-8.

Comment: Resolvi adicionando a tag no web.config: `<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="pt-br"/>`, dentro da seção `<system.web>`. Grato!

Comment: Use esse encoding: "iso-8859-1" que é português

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Como já mencionei nos comentários dessa pergunta, resolvi o problema adicionando essa tag ao meu arquivo web.config:

`<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="pt-br"/>`

Ficou assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem uma outra coisa que descobri que pode também afetar o reconhecimento de caracteres, que é o formato do arquivo.

Voltei a ter problemas com reconhecimento de caracteres após a implementação dessa tag no web.config do projeto.

Dessa vez era em apenas algumas páginas onde a palavra `"Descrição"`aparecia como `"Descri??o"`.

Tentei algumas modificações, como colocar o encode na tag com o "iso-8859-1". Isso só piorou a situação pois o Bootstrap não é compatível e o problema anterior havia voltado.

Então resolvi ver o formato dos arquivos *cshtml* e descobri que nessas páginas que estavam dando esse problema o encode estava como ANSI. Se você abrir o arquivo com o bloco de notas, por exemplo, e pedir "Salvar Como", a janela para escolher o arquivo e local de destino mostra o encode atual dele. Então só o que fiz foi alterar para utf-8 e salvar. E então essas páginas voltaram a mostrar os caracteres corretamente.

Como alterei o padrão desses arquivos para ANSI? Não sei!

Mas enfim, problema resolvido novamente.

Answer (score 4):

Eu resolvi colocando no `web.config`:

```xml
<system.web>
    <globalization
         fileEncoding="iso-8859-1"
         requestEncoding="iso-8859-1"
         responseEncoding="iso-8859-1"
         culture="pt-BR"
         uiCulture="pt-BR"
    />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 2):

Verifique o seu arquivo de configuração  ( `WEB.CONFIG` ). Adicione a tag abaixo dentro de `system.web`, deve funcionar.

```
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-
8" culture="pt-br"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

No meu caso modifiquei a codificação do arquivo salvo.

Fiz o seguinte passo no VS

Menu "File"-> "Advanced Save Options" e Selecionei "Unicode(UTF-8 with signature)-Codepage 65001"

Usando Asp.net Core

Funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Tenho a solução para o seu problema, siga os seguintes passos:
1. Abra o arquivo que contem as palavras com acentuação;
2. Vá ao **File->Save As**;
3. E lá carregue na setinha do botão *Save* e, *Save with Encoding*.
4. De seguida escolha a opção do UTF-8.
5. Não se preocupe se o VS pedir para substituir o ficheiro.

Arranque o projecto e veja.