# Problemas com acentuação Asp.Net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, view

Estou usando um `foreach` na minha `View`, mas estou com problemas com acentuação, observe o código:

```
@foreach (Area areas in Model.ListAreas) {
    @:{ id:@areas.Cod_Area, text: '@areas.Desc_Area'},
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observação: Já foi adicionado o meta charset no head da página.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Porque repetir a pergunta? [Problemas de Acentuação na View - Aps.Net c#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191094/54880)

Comment: A acentuação está vindo correta do backend?

Comment: Essa pergunta parece ter o que você precisa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7920/como-resolver-problemas-de-acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-asp-net-mvc?rq=1